# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException while reading iterator map

Tags: java

```
    public void removeInActiveRateValidators(long rateMonitorTimeout) {
            log.error("JKUMAR:::::::exectuing remove method"+rateMonitorTimeout+"   "+rateValidators.size());
            Iterator<RateValidator> iter = rateValidators.values().iterator();
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long removed = 0;
            try {
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    log.error("iterator valuessssssssssssss"+iter.next().toString());
                    log.error("last update time"+iter.next().getLastUpdate());
                    RateValidator mtr = iter.next();
                    log.error("JKUMAR:::::exectuing while loop");
                    if (now - mtr.getLastUpdate() > rateMonitorTimeout) {
                            log.error("Executing if condition in while loopt");
                            iter.remove();
                            removed++;
                    }
            }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                    log.error("Exception in removeInActiveRateValidators  entries::" +e);
            }
            log.error("JKUMAR:::: after try in remove method");
             if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
                 log.info("Removed " + removed + " rate monitors, inactive for more than " +
                            rateMonitorTimeout + " ms");
             }
    }
```

i am getting the following error

2017-01-04T05:33:32,469:ERROR:[Timer-optionsmonitor]:OptionsRateMonitor:-:Exception in removeInActiveRateValidators  entries::java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Comment: You call `iter.next()` several times at each iteration, call it only once .

Comment: You are invoking `iter.next()` 3 times within your loop

Comment: Thanks for reply, can you please explain briefly

Comment: while (iter.hasNext()) {
            RateValidator mtr = iter.next();
              if (now - mtr.getLastUpdate() > rateMonitorTimeout) {
                log.error("Executing if condition in while loopt");
                iter.remove();
                removed++;
            }
        }

Comment: Are you getting the same error for the modified code?

Comment: Tip: Stack Overflow is a terrible debugger.

Comment: yes, Mr.Peter 
if possible can you please give fix

Comment: Don't completely change your question after you've received an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are advancing the iterator multiple times inside the while loop. You should only advance it once, since the loop's condition only guarantees that there is at least one more element to iterate over.

```
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            RateValidator mtr = iter.next();
            log.error("iterator valuessssssssssssss"+mtr.toString());
            log.error("last update time"+mtr.getLastUpdate());
            log.error("JKUMAR:::::exectuing while loop");
            if (now - mtr.getLastUpdate() > rateMonitorTimeout) {
                log.error("Executing if condition in while loopt");
                iter.remove();
                removed++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Eran, but can you please remove the wrong statement in code

Comment: @KumarUppu What wrong statement?

Comment: i am asking, where is the bug? , please mention the bug line, if possible can  you remove the bug

Comment: Eran, i am asking where is the bug?, please mention the line, if possible give a fix

Comment: @KumarUppu My answer contains the fixed code. You can see that instead of calling iter.next() multiple times, I only call it once.